# Create View with Count in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, view, count

I need to create a View in SQL by counting the number of tasks an employee has been given but only show an employee who has more than 3 tasks. The problem I got is showing the count in the view. The error I'm getting is "missing right parenthesis"

```
CREATE VIEW EMPLOYEE_TASKS (E.EMPLOYEE_ID, E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, 
T.TASK_ID)

AS SELECT COUNT T.TASK_ID

FROM EMPLOYEE E, TASK T

WHERE E.EMPLOYEE_ID = T.TASK_ID

AND COUNT(T.TASK_ID) > 3;
```

Comment: please provide schema and some data in order to reproduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code just makes no sense.  I suspect you want:

```
CREATE VIEW EMPLOYEE_TASKS AS
    SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID, E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME, COUNT(*) as num_tasks
    FROM EMPLOYEE E JOIN
         TASK T
         ON E.EMPLOYEE_ID = T.TASK_ID
    GROUP BY E.EMPLOYEE_ID, E.FIRST_NAME, E.LAST_NAME
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 3;
```

Comment: Thanks. How does the count work if I'm not stating which column to count?

Comment: You don't need to specify a column name : `COUNT(*)` just calculates how many rows where aggredated by the `GROUP BY` clause, which is actually the information you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

When creating a view you can optionally provide a parenthetical list of column names just after the view name, however, that list should not be in alias.column_name format, you just provided the column names. Furthermore, if you do provide the optional list of column names, the projection (select list) of the query which defines the view should have the same number of column in its projection as in the column alias list.

Currently you have the following problems with your view definition:

1. You have table aliases (`E.` and `T.`) in the column alias list
2. You have only one column in the query projection but four aliases in the views column alias list
3. `COUNT T.TASK_ID` is not a valid column expression, `count(t.task_id)` is.
4. You use `COUNT(T.TASK_ID)` in the `WHERE` clause, however, that's an aggregate function which isn't allowed in the `WHERE`clause.

Answer (score 0):

"count" is a function. it needs arguments in parenthesis :

```
...

AS SELECT COUNT(T.TASK_ID)

...
```